# Can MSM (Merge Module) files be used within Inno-Setup?

Tags: soap, inno-setup, merge-module

Can I include a MSM file and execute it within Inno-Setup? If not, how would I properly install a merge module? I am needing to install SOAP3 with my application and need a bit of guidance. Will I have to wrap the MSM into a custom MSI and then have Inno execute the MSI file? What would I use to create a clean and stupid MSI file for the MSM? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately it can't, but your Visual Studio can create "Setup and Deployment" projects containing the msm's which you can include.
Follow these steps:

1. Open Visual Studio and create a new project: Other Project Types - Setup and Deployment - Visual Studio Installer
2. Select Setup Project and give it an appropriate name
3. Right click the project in the solution explorer and select Add Merge Module
4. Build your project, now you will have an msi file that you can include in your inno setup project
5. Add the File to the Files section of your inno setup project
6. Finally specify a run command using msiexec.  (run msiexec from the command prompt to view its options)